# Login to Rally using app sdk

Tags: rally

How I can programmatically login to Rally, using app sdk? I use it outside Rally. It redirects to login page first. And I want to login without user entering credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rally has a tool known as the LoginKey that can be used to help with external authentication for apps. If you are trying to get a report or an app to show inside a wiki or internal webpage without logging in that is your best bet.

There are some security concerns with showing Rally data without authentication and before sharing the LoginKey we want to make sure our customers are making an informed choice. If you would like to learn more please open a support case directly with [Rally Support](http://www.rallydev.com/support/support_case/).