# Xml datasource from Infopath

Tags: rally

I am pretty new to this, so I hope youll bear with me. Is there a way to sign into rally wsapi using a url? I have tried https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.31/hierarchicalrequirement?username=someuserid&password=somepassword but that doesnt seem to work. I still get a login prompt.

I can sign in and pull up all of the info I need, but if I pull this data source from infopath it cant sign into or give anyone a prompt even to access the source once it's out on sharepoint. Ive tried everything I can think of, tried signing in using a customized udcx file, etc. Wasnt able to get curl to both authenticate through our proxy and to Rally either. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Rally's AppSDK has a LoginKey tool that can facilitate view-only access for external systems. [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922367/charles-ferentchak) wrote up a great answer to this in [Login to Rally using app sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246913/login-to-rally-using-app-sdk). You do have to file a case with Rally Support (rallysupport@rallydev.com) to obtain access to the tool.

Answer (score 0):

For using curl, you should be able to pass your username and password on the command line like this (from the rally api doc):

curl -u 'curmudgeon@rallydev.com:SecretPassword' https://blah.blah.blah

For using other tools, if they have a mechanism for using "basic authentication", you should be good to go.

Comment: I did try that, but it didnt work. The username and password has to be the account that signs into our proxy. Otherwise that kills it. But then that doesnt leave room for signing into Rally.

Comment: I don't have a proxy to play with, but I thought that the proxy should use capital U and the target lowercase u.  As in curl -u 'username_on_rally:password' -U 'username_on_proxy:password' blah blah

Comment: It's been a while since I've used curl with a proxy, but the syntax that's worked for me in the past was: curl -u 'rallyuser@company.com:rallypassword' --proxy-user 'internalusername:proxypassword' https://rally1.rallydev.com/blah

Comment: The above should work for Linux flavors of curl - not sure about Windows.