# Is it possible to view app like burndown chart outside of Rally with specific authentication information in javascript?

Tags: rally

I am pretty new user of Rally.
In my project we want to embed Rally iteration burndown chart in our own application.
So i use Rally App Sdk to get the chart and I can get it successfully.
But every time user have to input user name and password manually and then view the chart. It's a very poor user experience.

So I wonder if there is a way to specify username and password in the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer to this question useful:

[Login to Rally using app sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246913/login-to-rally-using-app-sdk)